# Get _gid values through Google analytics reporting API, is it possible?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have noticed that in [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/), the clientId assigned by google analytics itself to uniquely identify a device is not available to query through any of reporting APIs but it's nevertheless possible (ga:clientId).

Does someone know if it's possible to request the values of **_gid** cookies ?
I'v tried [ga:gid] | [ga:gId] | [ga:googleId] but it doesn't to work...

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dimensions and metrics](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) explorer lists the dimensions and metrics that can be used with the Google Analytics reporting api

the cookies you are referring to are mainly used for internal processing for the data and are not actually "stored" if you could find them you can store them as a custom dimension into your google analytics account  and then have access to them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's the solution that i've find for the future. But i need to have this data for the past and this data was not stored in a custom dimension for the past in this Google Analytics property...

Comment: There is no way to insert past data into google analytics.  If the data was not stored by you into a custom dimension then it does not exist.   The only dimensions and metrics you can retrieve are the ones listed in the metadata list.   Check the Google analytics website if you cant see it there then you cant get it out of the API.

Comment: Thanks. It's KO! i thought that this data was nevertheless saved by GA...